# Mac / CAM entries from non-Cisco switches with Q-BRIDGE-MIB

Tags: cisco, switch, snmp, brocade, foundry

How do I do community string Indexing for other switches like **D link DES 3526** and **Brocade Fastiron SX800**?

I am running a java program to poll a specific vlan on a **Brocade sx 800** l3 switch.  The program throws a "Time out error". I then checked the switch log , which says **community string invalid**. I'm having trouble with the syntax "community@vlanid".

Displaying all Vlans and their names:

[image: Displaying all Vlans and their names]

Could someone please tell me the community string indexing for switches other than Cisco?

#### EDIT

I tried the commands in CLI with Net-SNMP:

Poll sysDescr:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.21.200.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: DES-3526 Fast-Ethernet Switch
```

Poll dot1dTpFdbAddress (default Vlan):

```
snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 10.21.200.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.0.27.17.189.90.220 = Hex-STRING: 00 1B 11 BD 5A DC
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.4.254.127.149.86.136 = Hex-STRING: 04 FE 7F 95 56 88
```

Poll dot1dTpFdbAddress (default Vlan4):

```
snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public@4 10.21.200.4 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
Timeout: No Response from 10.21.200.4
```

Netdisco listing all ports and corresponding MAC addresses
[image: Netdisco listing all ports and corresponding MAC addresses]

I want to retrieve all MAC addresses from individual ports. The **Q-Bridge MIB** shows all the ports on the switch but unfortunately the MAC address OID is not accessible. On the other hand, using the **Bridge MIB** lists only MAC addresses from the default Vlan.
P.S: the community string indexing ( coommstring@vlanid ) to access other vlans only works with CISCO switches.

Comment: Which OIDs are you polling?  FYI, other than [BRIDGE-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&mibName=BRIDGE-MIB) or [Q-BRIDGE-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&mibName=Q-BRIDGE-MIB), I cannot think of OIDs which require indexing with vlan id

Comment: Yes,the Bridge MIB only. I am trying to poll dot1dTpFdbAddress to retrieve the MAC Table from a specific Vlanid (vlan:4) on the Brocade SX 800 switch (OID : 1.3.6.2.3.1.17.4.3.1.1 ). I believe there is an error in the syntax public@4 .Can you pls clarify that?

Comment: Diagnostic test... Does polling [sysdescr](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) work?  `snmpget -v 2c -c public [SWITCH-ADDRESS-HERE] .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`

Comment: Yes it worked. I could retrieve the list of available vlans on the Sx 800 switch. I could also get the MAC table for the default Vlanid , which in my case is vlanid 1. The problem is retrieving MAC tables from other Vlans. FYI I am coding in Java environment ( SNMP4j). Thank you.

Comment: Now let's validate that the switch is behaving.  Please try this (from the CLI with [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/)), `snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public@4 [SWITCH-ADDRESS-HERE] .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1`.  Does that return what you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me the community string indexing for switches other than Cisco?

### Edit:

This is how to poll Q-BRIDGE-MIB for mac-addresses from the only non-Cisco I have, a DLink DGS-3200.  I'm *not* using [community@vlan] for non-Cisco switches.  You're correct that this indexing only applies to Ciscos.  I expect any non-Cisco switch, which supports Q-BRIDGE-MIB to work the same way.

#### Polling [sysDescr](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=sysDescr&translate=Translate) to document the switch under test

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ # Demo from a DLink DGS-3200 switch
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq 172.16.1.2 sysdescr
sysDescr.0 "DGS-3200-10 Gigabit Ethernet Switch"
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### Walking [dot1qVlanStaticName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qVlanStaticName&translate=Translate): List Vlans and their text names

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.1
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.4.3.1.1.1 = STRING: "default"
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qFdbDynamicCount](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qFdbDynamicCount&translate=Translate): Number of mac addresses known

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public  172.16.1.2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.1.1.2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.1.1.2.1 = Counter32: 17
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qVlanCurrentEgressPorts](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qVlanCurrentEgressPorts&translate=Translate): bitmap of ports in the vlan

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.2.1.4
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.4.2.1.4.2562.1 = Hex-STRING: FF C0 00 00
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate): All MAC Addresses learned

The mac-addresses show up as a string of six decimal digits in the indexes to [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate).  Note that I have a downstream switch connected to this switch on port `1/5`...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.101.22.202.65 = INTEGER: 5
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.189.7.134.128 = INTEGER: 5
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.189.7.134.129 = INTEGER: 5
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.29.161.205.83.70 = INTEGER: 9
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.48.27.188.167.215 = INTEGER: 2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.192.183.110.158.29 = INTEGER: 3

... more entries here
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1dBasePortIfIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1dBasePortIfIndex&translate=Translate): Map values from [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate) to an [ifIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifIndex&translate=Translate)

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq 172.16.1.26 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[1] 1
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[2] 2
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[3] 3
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[4] 4
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[5] 5
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[6] 6
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[7] 7
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[8] 8
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[9] 9
dot1dBasePortIfIndex[10] 10
```

#### [ifName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifName&translate=Translate): Map values from [ifIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifIndex&translate=Translate) to an [ifName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ifName&translate=Translate)

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq 172.16.1.26 ifName
ifName[1] 1/1
ifName[2] 1/2
ifName[3] 1/3
ifName[4] 1/4
ifName[5] 1/5
ifName[6] 1/6
ifName[7] 1/7
ifName[8] 1/8
ifName[9] 1/9
ifName[10] 1/10
ifName[5121] System
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

---

### ORIGINAL:

There is a mistake in your OID, you're using `1.3.6.2.3.1.17.4.3.1.1`; however, [dot1dTpFdbAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=dot1dTpFdbAddress) is `1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1`.

The difference is changing some octets, below...

```
OID Incorrect: 1.3.6.2.3.1.17.4.3.1.1   <--- Not this
OID Corrected: 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1   <--- Use this
                     ^ ^
                     | |
```

Comment: the following command returns nothing `snmpwalk -c public -v1 netgearpt01 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1` i am trying to achieve http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/44800-mactoport44800.html on a `netgear gs752txs`. that guide works for a `netgear gsm7328s` with v2c i get the following `snmpwalk -c public -v2c netgearpt01 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID`

Comment: @sharif, what happens when you poll `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public netgearpt01 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1`?  That just gets `sysDescr` from the switch.

Comment: yes it does. i get `SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: GS752TXS ProSafe 52-Port Gigabit Stackable Smart Switch with 10G uplinks, 6.1.0.12, B5.2.0.1`. Say i have a network of switches. i want to locate what swictch and prot it is connected to currently. mac address is `00:04:f2:e2:67:62`. running `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public netgearpt02 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2` gives a me a long list. how would i convert the mac address to the 6 digit hex number to find out what port it is on? `netgearpt02` is my top level switch

Comment: Consider the first value returned above when I walked `dot1qTpFdbPort` ; the first entry I got was `BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.101.22.202.65 = 5` back.  `0.13.101.22.202.651` is the mac-address encoded as decimal (i.e. `00:13:65:16:ca:41`).  That is learned on `dot1dBasePortIfIndex` 5, which of course maps to an `ifName` as shown above.

Comment: in php how would i encode `00:04:f2:e2:67:62` to represent the decimal

Comment: PHP isn't really our thing here, but you certainly could get help with this on [so]

Comment: just to clarify, all i need to do is snmpwalk the `dot1qTpFdbPort` and grep for the decimal representation? this should grab the port the mac is connected to. if this port is connected to another switch i keep doing the same until i get it? `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.0.94.0.1.2 = INTEGER: 50`. the port is the last digits of the string?

Comment: 50 is the port index.  Otherwise the algorithm you described works.  You should ping sweep the subnet before polls to ensure maximum macs in the switch table.