# What is the difference between ipNetToMediaPhysAddress and dot1qTpFdbPort?

Tags: switch, snmp, management, mac-address

I see the object description of **[ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)** from ipNetToMediaTable as the **"The media-dependent `physical' address"**. Putting it simple, does it mean it returns the MAC addresses of all the directly connected nodes/devices?

- For example,
  **snmpbulkwalk  -v 2c -c public 10.21.200.201 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2**
  Polling this OID (1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2) on a L3 switch-(Ip:10.21.200.201) (Brocade FastIron Sx 800) returns me approximately 1800 entries which is a mixture of both **L2/L3 devices** and **some PCs**. But polling the same OID on an **L2 switch** returns me only four entries: 2 broadcast entries,the previous L3 switch's MAC address and the L2 switch's self MAC address. There are PCs attached to this L2 switch(DLINK DES 3526 model). **Why can't I see MAC addresses of the attached PCs on polling the OID for the above switch?**

Also can someone throw light on the fine differences between the MAC addresses learned from **[dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)** and  **[ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't I see MAC addresses of the attached PCs on polling the OID for the above switch?

When you poll `1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2`, you're polling [ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true), which is the ARP table of the switch.  Pure Layer2 switches do not have a large ARP table because they are merely switching instead of routing.  Switching does *not* require an ARP table.

> Also can someone throw light on the fine differences between the MAC addresses learned from dot1qTpFdbPort and ipNetToMediaPhysAddress?

- [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) maps the Layer2 mac-address recently learned by the switch to a physical port on the switch.
- [ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) polls the ARP table of something.  The only things that show up in the ARP table are things which had recent, direct IP-layer communication with the thing being polled.  IP-layer communication occurs when packets are routed, or for instance if you ssh directly to a Layer2 switch's management IP.

If you poll [ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) on a *router* attached to the Brocade / DLink Layer2 switches, you will see the same [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) mac-addresses from the Layer2 switches in that router's ARP table (assuming you did a recent ping sweep of the relevant subnets through the router in question).  Also note that if VRRP / HSRP / GLBP are used on the subnet, you should poll [ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) both [FHRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Hop_Redundancy_Protocols) peers, due to potential asymmetric routing.

#### ARP / Mac Polling Technique

I have to do a lot of polling like this where I map mac addresses / ports found in [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) to IP addresses from [ipNetToMediaPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=ipNetToMediaPhysAddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true).  I always ping sweep (with a tool like [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/)... `nmap -sP 192.0.2.0/24`) through the subnet just before I poll the router / downstream switches with snmp.

---

#### [Edit Questions in Comments]

> So polling the dot1qTpFdbPort on an L2 switch guarantees that the resulting MAC addresses/ports are the ones directly connected to the L2 switch?

Not quite true... polling [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) guarantees that these are the mac addresses learned by the switch, or statically configured on the switch. A few notable exceptions to your statement:

- If you chain Layer2 switches together (including most [FHRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Hop_Redundancy_Protocols) topologies), you'll see mac addresses learned from downstream switches.  By definition, macs learned from downstream switches are not directly connected.  If you have Cisco switces, [cdpCacheTable](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1) is very useful for untangling relationships between switches.
- Some mac-addresses in [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) could be owned by the switch itself, instead of being directly connected to it.
- If you have LACP aggregates in your topology, the vendor might do things like associate mac-addresses with a physical port in that LACP aggregate, instead of learning the mac through the LACP aggregate.  Somewhere in the standards I saw discussion about this, but I can't remember where offhand.
- Some switches have vendor-specific features (often they are security features) which completely remove visibility of mac-addresses from [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true).  YMMV

All the above means you cannot 100% guarantee that the mac returned by [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) is *directly connected* to the switch.  If you take care of these kind of issues in your code, then you shouldn't have problems.

> PS: I haven't tried ICMP sweep (ping sweep).Is it really necessary to do ping sweep so as to obtain the complete topology of the network?

Ping sweeps mitigate these two issues:

- Switch mac-table aging timers vary, but they can be quite low (i.e. 5 minutes).  It's not uncommon to see mismatched router ARP and switch mac table timers in a network.  Sometimes the ARP and switch mac tables get out of sync.  You stand the best chance of matching switch mac table to router ARP table if you ping sweep just before your polls.
- Some end-points may only receive unidirectional traffic (i.e. a multicast stream).  If someone is passively watching or listening to a unidirectional stream, their PC might not refresh the switch mac-address table very often.

Comment: Here in my case the L3 switch which is connected to several L2 switches and Pcs does routing as well. So I will try mapping them to the lower level devices and check. So polling the dot1qTpFdbPort on an L2 switch guarantees that the resulting MAC addresses/ports are the ones directly connected to the L2 switch? PS: I haven't tried ICMP sweep (ping sweep).Is it really necessary to do ping sweep so as to obtain the complete topology of the network?

Comment: I will try eliminating the first and fourth exceptions in my program. Does your second exception mean that the switch's individual ports can have unique mac addresses and that may be listed in the result of polling dot1qTpFdbPort?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Is there any specific OID that shows all the switch interfaces' mac addresses alone? And how to be certain that there is a downstream switch connected to a specific port on a switch just by looking at the result? In one of your earlier ports you have mentioned:[http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6070/mac-cam-entries-from-non-cisco-switches-with-q-bridge-mib]

Comment: Use [dot1dTpFdbStatus](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.3#oidContent).  Value 4 is a switch-owned mac.

Comment: If I keep recursively eliminating the MAC addresses obtained from dot1qTpFdbPort of all the connected L2 switches from the MAC entries of ipNetToMediaPhysAddress (i.e., the common MAC ids in both the tables), will I be able to see only MAC entries of those PCs that are directly connected to the L3 switch?  There are over 250 heterogeneous switches,routers and approximately 2500 nodes(PCs) in the organization with an L3 switch at the top of the hierarchy. Trying to map the connectivity of  will be a strenuous task.So I would like to know if the elimination logic will work in the first place?

Comment: Can we continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations)?